# Unexpected behaviour of iterator on String

Tags: string, scala, iterator

Can anyone explain why these iterators behave differently? I generally expect a String to act like an `IndexedSeq[Char]`. Is this documented anywhere?

```
val si: Iterator[Char] = "uvwxyz".iterator
val vi: Iterator[Char] = "uvwxyz".toIndexedSeq.iterator

val sr = for (i <- 1 to 3) 
           yield si take 2 mkString
  //sr: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[String] = Vector(uv, uv, uv)

val vr = for (i <- 1 to 3) 
           yield vi take 2 mkString
  //vr: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[String] = Vector(uv, wx, yz)
```

Comment: Seems like `.take(2)` in the first example makes a copy of the iterator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are no guarantees about the state of the iterator after you invoke `take` on it.

The problem with iterators is that many useful operations can only be implemented by causing side effects. All these operations have a specified direct effect but may also have side effects that cannot be specified (or would complicate the implementation).

In the case of `take` there are implementations that clone the internal state of the iterator and others that advance the iterator. If you want to guarantee the absence of side-effects you will have to use immutable data structures, in any other case your code should only rely on direct effects.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder why something so crucially important to what an `Iterator` does would be unspecified?

Comment: @LuigiPlinge, there were some improvements in trunk at http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.collection.Iterator: see after "Consider this example for safe and unsafe use".